# Can a method find out the "this" of its parent object?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I've come up with a particular sort function that I want to put in the prototype of some Array based object (I'll use Array itself here). I can do

```
Array.prototype.specialSort = function...
```

but what I'd really like to do is

```
Array.prototype.sort.special = function...
```

the problem, of course, is that when it's called, the latter won't know about the Array object, it will only know about the sort, so it can't sort. Is there any magical incantation to pass a "this" down the tree?

Secondary question (since the answer to the primary question is likely "no"): What would you do to implement the notion of "sub-methods" with maximum elegance?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Also, the "this" pointer has **nothing** to do with how a function is defined. It's completely determined at invocation time.

Comment: Also, don't bother trying to subclass Array - you really can't succeed at that: http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Comment: Pointy: The "this" pointer is used when defining a method, which is what I hope to be doing here. It would be a sorting method, but rather than overriding the built-in sort method, it would be a distinct method. But because it is a method that sorts, and because I could maybe have several special sorting functions, it would be appealing to be able to "group" them all under the existing sort function. But if I do that, they don't know about the Array that they're supposed to be sorting.

Comment: No.  The "this" pointer is *set* by the runtime when *calling* a method. And no, it won't work to call it like that. You'd have to use `arr.sort.special.call(arr, ...)`

Comment: I'm not sure what is suggesting that I don't know when "this" gets its value. The method only runs when it is called, so of course that's when "this" would get a value. But the method has to be written before then, and I would use that pointer in my code.

Comment: @Roy J - are you sure that what you're trying to accomplish cannot be achieved by just passing a function as a parameter to sort() so that you determine how the items are sorted? (it's difficult to tell what your intention is here).

Comment: samandmore: Yes, the sorting can be achieved by passing a comparison function to sort() -- that's what would be happening at some level. My intention was to find some elegant way of packaging up that function with the object, to make the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly close to what you want:

```
Array.prototype.sort = function () {
  return {
      self: this;
    , special: function () {
        return sortLogic (self);
      }
  };
};

var xs = [1, 2, 3];
xs.sort ().special ();
```

---

Another option would be to use `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`, especially if you want `arr.sort ()` to sort the list as normal.

```
Array.prototype.sort.special.call (arr, arg1, arg2, etc);
```

---

Using the second method over the first allows one to use the `call` and `apply` methods easily on the `sort.special` method. Could be useful when doing something like the following:

```
function () {
  Array.prototype.sort.special.call (arguments);
}
```

---

If you want both worlds, something like this could work:

```
Array.prototype.sort = (function () {
  var special = function () {
    if (this [0] > this [1]) {
      var tmp = this [0];
      this [0] = this [1];
      this [1] = tmp;
    }
    return this;
  };
  var sort = function () {
    var context = this;
    return {
      special: function () {
        return special.apply (context, arguments)
      }
    };
  };
  sort.special = special;
  return sort;
}) ();


/*** Example Below ***/


function foo () {
  Array.prototype.sort.special.call (arguments);
  var xs = [5, 2, 3];
  xs.sort ().special ();
  alert (arguments);
  alert (xs);
}

foo (9, 6);
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to redefine the "sort" function on native Array

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance to both **Pointy** and **trinithis**. I think I am clear on the subject now. The sticking point is that, although sort() is a method of the Array, if it's not invoked, it's just a member (or property), so it has no "this". I was wanting the "this" it would have had if it had been invoked. And since I was invoking *something* at the end of the chain, I was kind of hoping there was some magic that would keep it all method-y. But no.

What I would probably do is have a separate "sorts" method to act as the grouper for my special methods, and leave the existing sort alone.